# Lost access to my Virtual Machine on linux server pool after I used sys-unconfig command as root

Tags: linux, networking, virtual-machines

The network admin gave me an IP address for Redhat VM on his Linux server pool; but lately I used the `sys-unconfig` command as a root user, and now I lost my access to the V-Machine; I cannot contact my network admin for now, he is away; so is there any other way I can get my access back without the need for the network admin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the VM has been restored to defaults, maybe it will get a DHCP address. If you can find this, you should be able to connect again.
Otherwise, without access to the hosting server pool, I can't figure out how to gain control again.